Checking oAuth token expiration in FlaskAppBuilder App
Does anyone know how to check token expiry on requests in a Flask AppBuilder app. I'm specifically talking Superset here, but I think the same would apply anywhere.
I've got an OAUTH configuration for Keycloak and the app is authenticating just fine using auth_type = AUTH_OAUTH and an AuthOAuthView descendant. So, the user gets logged in and by default the session["oauth"] is set to the token - this is all mostly default FAB behaviour.
It seems that Authlib (used for the OAuth) has checking and refreshing tokens built-in, but I can't see that this is being called for each request. In fact what happens is that the app thinks the user is logged in when the token has expired and allows the request to proceed, right down to getting data for a chart, at which point we make a 3rd party query using the token which fails. So we get an ugly DB engine Error and the user is logged out, re-authenticates, gets a new token and everything is happy again.
I feel like a piece of the puzzle is missing somewhere to check the OAuth token for validity before even serving the request, trying to refresh the token if possible, logging out and redirecting before showing UI to the chart level.
Has anyone had this problem and resolved it?
Thanks
